# Proof that a function is surjective to R

Tags: functions, proof-writing

I'm having difficulties proving that the function

> $$\frac{\sin(\frac1x)}{x^2}$$

is surjective to $\mathbb R$. on the interval $(0,10]$.

I tried to use the intermediate theorem, but that of course only works on a closed interval. I know the roots $$\frac{1}{\pi n}$$ where $n\in Z/0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is continuous and $(0,10]$ is connected, so you just need to show that $\sup_{x \in (0,10]} f(x) = +\infty$, and $\inf_{x \in (0,10]} f(x) = -\infty$, where $f(x) = \frac{\sin \frac{1}{x}}{x^2}$.

We have $\frac{1}{x} = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2 \pi n $ **iff** $x = \frac{1}{{\frac{\pi}{2} + 2 \pi n}}$, and in this case we have $f(x) = (\frac{\pi}{2} + 2 \pi n)^2$, so we see that $\sup_{x \in (0,10]} f(x) = +\infty$.

In a similar manner,  $\frac{1}{x} = \frac{3\pi}{2} + 2 \pi n $ **iff** $x = \frac{1}{{\frac{3\pi}{2} + 2 \pi n}}$, and in this case we have $f(x) = -(\frac{3\pi}{2} + 2 \pi n)^2$, so we see that $\inf_{x \in (0,10]} f(x) = -\infty$.

**Note**: Using the above, you can see using the intermediate value theorem that if you choose the closed interval $[\frac{1}{{\frac{3\pi}{2} + 2 \pi n}}, \frac{1}{{\frac{\pi}{2} + 2 \pi n}}]$, then $f$ takes all values in $[ -(\frac{3\pi}{2} + 2 \pi n)^2, (\frac{\pi}{2} + 2 \pi n)^2 ] $. Hence if you take $n$ large enough, this will include any $y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I think you might have read a small part of my question wrong, $f(x) = \frac{\sin \frac{1}{x^2}}{x^2}$ is supposed to be $f(x) = \frac{\sin \frac{1}{x}}{x^2}$. The x inside the sin is not of 2nd degree.

Comment: Oops, excuse me! I just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Look at these numbers $\frac{2}{(4n+1)\pi}$ and $\frac{2}{(4n+3)\pi}$  for $n\in \mathbb{N}$
We can make the function arbitrarily high(or low) with large enough n.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't learned anything about sequences yet.

Comment: just think of it like an ordered list of numbers, we get one for n=0, n=1, n=2, &c